# Java Swing: Expanding TreeNode

Tags: java, swing

I am working on customizing a closed source client application. It has a tree in the UI and exposed only a method to get the selected node. It returns a subclass of TreeNode. And there is no way to get a reference to the parent tree. Now i want to expand the selected node upto its leaves.

Is there any way to get a reference to the JTree component from a DefaultMutableTreeNode? I am planning to use the JTree.expandPath() but I only have the reference to the treenode.

I'm new to Swing and any suggestions to achieve this are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, only the JTree is aware of the expansion state, there is no such information in the TreeNodes. The TreeNodes are on the ["model"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)#Loosely-Coupled_and_MVC) side, and have no pointer on the JTree (at least not default ones, you can of course make your own with a reference, but it breaks a bit the pattern).

You should reconsider the place where you want to make this expansion for a place in which you have access to the JTree (provide maybe more details about your context, to know more what you want to do, and in which circumstances).

Comment: I am working on customizing a closed source client application. It has a tree in the UI and exposed only a method to get the selected node. It returns a subclass of TreeNode. And there is no way to get a reference to the parent tree. Now i want to expand the selected node upto its leaves.

Comment: @sarav - In this case, I'm afraid you are out of luck. If you don't have any other access than the TreeNodes, you can't control the expanded state of the JTree. There could be a (very) dirty way to do it, if you had access to the top window/component (or any component in the same window), and were sure that the structure of it is static, you could make your way to the JTree from there.

Comment: @sarav - (quick note, consider editing your question with these new details, for everyone to see more clearly the whole situation)

Comment: thanks for the replies. yup, i'm out of luck here. looking for some other work around.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source for `DefaultMutableTreeNode`, I can't see any nice way to do it, but you could try one of the following:

- Extend `DefaultMutableTreeNode` and store the reference to your tree
- The default node has a concept of a "user object". You *could* set the reference to the tree as this object. It's completely un-type safe, but would probably work. **EDIT:** Actually, looking closer at how user object is used (as a textual representation of the tree path and in `toString()`), setting the user object in this way would be massacring the API's intended use. So: nasty, but might work.

Comment: "have no pointer on the JTree"

Answer (score 0):

The tree node is an element from the tree model. As a consequence, it doesn't have any reference to the Tree that is its view.

What could be interesting is to know in which object you are : since you want to react to a mouse event, I guess you have access to the view layer (at least by getting back the component originating the MouseEvent, which should be the JTree). If so, you can get the selected row and call [expandPath](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#expandPath(javax.swing.tree.TreePath)). Building the TreePath from the DefaultMutableTreeNode is left as an exercise :-)

**EDIT** From the below comments, let me clarify my answer.
You'll have to call [expandPath](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#expandPath(javax.swing.tree.TreePath)) using a [TreePath](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreePath.html) generated by simply calling [getPath](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html#getPath()) on your DefaultMutableTreeNode.

Comment: I don't see a reference to a mouse event in his question, though.

Comment: If it does happen to be in response to a user click though, `event.getSource()` is probably the nicest option.